# C# quiz random questions with no specific answer

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to make a c# quiz with a dictionary which randomly chooses a item inside of my dictionary.

I get 2 errors line 33,38 that I can't convert a string into a int.

I do not know how to fix my code so I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what to do or what I did wrong.

This is my code

```
 namespace RNG_QUIZ
  {
   class Program
   {
    static public void Main()
    {
        //maak een dictionary aan
        Console.WriteLine("Quiz");

        Dictionary<int, string> Questions =
                   new Dictionary<int, string>();

        //voeg vragen toe 
        //key koppelen aan vraag
        Questions.Add(11, "Vraag1");
        Questions.Add(12, "Vraag2");
        Questions.Add(13, "Vraag3");
        Questions.Add(14, "Vraag4");
        Questions.Add(15, "Vraag5");

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> ele1 in Questions)
        {  
            Console.WriteLine("{0} and {1}",
                      ele1.Key, ele1.Value);
        }

        List<string> keylist = new List<string>(Questions.Keys); //error   cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string>.KeyCollection' to 'int'

        Random rand = new Random();
        string randomKey = keylist[rand.Next(keylist.Count)];


        return Questions[randomKey]; //error cant convert from 'string' to int



        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Error

> The key for your `Dictionary<int,string>` is an int, so `return
>   Questions[randomKey];` is an issue because `randomKey` is declared as
>   a `string`.

Second Error

> `List<string> keylist = new List<string>(Questions.Keys); //error
>
>   cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,
>   string>.KeyCollection' to 'int'` This is an issue since
>   `Questions.Keys` is a `Dictionary<int,string>.KeyCollection` and you
>   are trying to assign it to a `List<int>`. You could however, do this
>   `var p = Questions.Keys.ToList();` and p will be a `List<int>`.

Coming back to what you want, you want to randomly pick a key from your `Dictionary` and set that as the question to display, so in your example you want to pick a random integer from the group {11,12,13,14,15} and you can pick a random number from a given `List<int>` like so

```
var randomKey = Questions.Keys.OrderBy(x => rand.Next()).First();
//Here Questions.Keys is a List<int>
```

The alternative method to get the random number is what the other poster @Ruchin Munjal had -

```
            var keylist = new List<int>();
            keylist.AddRange(Questions.Keys);
            var next = rand.Next(keylist.Count);
            var randomKey = keylist[next];
```

Wrapping it all up

```
            Console.WriteLine("Quiz");

            Dictionary<int, string> Questions =
                new Dictionary<int, string>();

            //voeg vragen toe 
            //key koppelen aan vraag
            Questions.Add(11, "Vraag1");
            Questions.Add(12, "Vraag2");
            Questions.Add(13, "Vraag3");
            Questions.Add(14, "Vraag4");
            Questions.Add(15, "Vraag5");

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> ele1 in Questions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} and {1}",
                    ele1.Key, ele1.Value);
            }

            Random rand = new Random();
            int randomKey = Questions.Keys.OrderBy(x => rand.Next()).First();

            Console.WriteLine(Questions[randomKey]);

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: @RufusL - Yes, sorry I had tested it with `.Take(1).Single()` and `.First()`, but on posting I changed it to `.Single()`. But `.First()` is the better option.

Comment: It would help if folks downvoting this answer could also mention what needs improvement.

Comment: The .Single call will throw an exception because there's more than one key in Questions.Keys

Comment: Thanks, I had updated it on Friday, after RufusL mentioned that as well, you'll see that from my comment above, but somehow posted the wrong version again.
I've updated and verified that it is the correct this time around.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to change to make this work:

1. First, you are trying to save all of your `int` keys into a `List<string>`, you need to declare your `List<>` to type `int`
2. You are giving `Questions.Keys` as a parameter to the constructor of your `List<>`, to fix this just give no arguments to
   the constructor and then save the Keys invoking the `ToList()`
   method.

   ```
   List<int> keylist = new List<int>(); // they key list should be int, since keys are declared as integers in your dictionary
   keylist = Questions.Keys.ToList();
   ```
3. It's easier to get a random index delimited by the number of questions, rather than getting the lowest and highest key values,
   and you can do it like this:

   ```
   Random rand = new Random();
   int countKeys = Questions.Keys.Count(); //get number of questions
   int randomIndex = rand.Next(0,countKeys); // get a random index from 0 to number of questions
   ```
4. You are using `return` in the main method, which is a `void` method. If what you are trying to do is to print the result, use
   `Console.WriteLine()`
5. And last but not least, getting the dictionary key by index, you just use `.ElementAt()`.

And that's it, putting all together would look something like this:

```
        //maak een dictionary aan
        Console.WriteLine("Quiz");

        Dictionary<int, string> Questions =
                   new Dictionary<int, string>();

        //voeg vragen toe 
        //key koppelen aan vraag
        Questions.Add(11, "Vraag1");
        Questions.Add(12, "Vraag2");
        Questions.Add(13, "Vraag3");
        Questions.Add(14, "Vraag4");
        Questions.Add(15, "Vraag5");

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> ele1 in Questions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} and {1}",
                      ele1.Key, ele1.Value);
        }

        List<int> keylist = new List<int>(); // they key list should be int, since keys are declared as integers in your dictionary

        keylist = Questions.Keys.ToList();

        Random rand = new Random();
        int countKeys = Questions.Keys.Count();
        int randomIndex = rand.Next(0,countKeys);

        Console.WriteLine(Questions.ElementAt(randomIndex).Key); //here you are giving a random index and getting the key that is holding that index

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: yea it displays a random question but also al the other "vraag 1 tm vraag5"

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line with the first error to

```
List<int> keylist = new List<int>(Questions.Select(x => x.Key));
```

Comment: or `List<int> keylist = Questions.Keys.ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Lists in C# are strongly typed. This means if you are creating a list of `strings` you can not add/insert a `int`. Your dictionary is of type `<int,string>` meaning your keys will be `int` and values will be `string`. You declared a list of `string` and are trying to insert keys which are of type `int`

dotnet errors are generally very explanatory.

You need to change code as below

```
  var keylist = new List<int>();
  keylist.AddRange(Questions.Keys);
```

Second error also has the same issue as above. You can change it to

```
 Random rand = new Random();
 var next= rand.Next(keylist.Count);
 var randomKey = keylist[next]; //note randomKey is int
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several answers describing problems with the sample code, so I won't go over it again here. But I think there may be a simpler way to get what you're after, so I'll offer an alternative.

If you want to pick a random item from the dictionary, then the `Key` is not important (**the sample code never actually uses the key except to try to pick a random value**), and you may as well be using a `List<T>` instead. Luckily, a dictionary has such a collection: a property named `Values`, and we can return a random value very easily if we create a list from them:

```
// Code to populate dictionary omitted

// Return a random value from the dictionary's Values collection
return Questions.Values.ToList()[rand.Next(Questions.Count)];
```

If for some reason you do need the key associated with the value, then we can do the same trick with the `Keys` collection, and then we have both:

```
// Get a random key from the dictionary's Keys collection
var randomKey = Questions.Keys.ToList()[rand.Next(Questions.Count)];

// Use that key to get a value
return Questions[randomKey];
```